# what does "missing : after property id" mean in the context of a simple map/reduce?

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

I have a set of objects in a mongodb database that have measurements embedded. I'm trying to do a map/reduce to get stats about the measurements. Well I ran into some problems with that so I just made it as simple as possible: get the number of measurements for each one.

```
m = function() {
    emit (mp, { meas:  this.measurements }); 
 };

r = function() {
    return { count: meas.length };
 };

 res = db.meas_points.mapReduce(m, r,
    {query : { measurements : {$exists: true}}},
    {out: { "measurements_stats" }} );
```

When I run this query I get an error:

`Mon Jan  2 16:05:53 SyntaxError: missing : after property id (shell):1`

I'm trying to see what this means in the context of my map/reduce but I'm just not seeing it. I lifted the code from the mongodb website ( http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/MapReduce Shell Example 2) and adapted it to my needs. Seems like I'm doing everything right but I keep getting this cryptic error. I'm not using the `id` field at all -- is it possible that I have a malformed record or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this line

```
return { count: meas.length };
```

It is not able to  resolve `meas` You need to modify the signature of the reduce function.

```
var r = function(mp, measValues) {
                      return Array.sum(measValues.length);
                  };
```

Here `measValues` passed to this reduce function itself is an array

Note: If `mp` in the map function is the id/key of your collection meas_points then change that line to `this.mp`

Comment: This question is so old that I have no idea how to mark an answer. So this one gets it for at least attempting to answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`{ "measurements_stats" }` is invalid syntax.

Did you mean an array?

Comment: Are you sure? The sample has `res = db.things.mapReduce(m, r, { out : "myoutput" } );`. I think I have to have it that way because of the `query`. If I change it to `, { out:  "price_stats"}` I get an error `"assertion" : "'out' has to be a string or an object"`